# Convert JSONObject to Yaml in JAVA 8

Tags: java, json, yaml, jackson-databind, snakeyaml

i am using jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.7.6  jar which is old version and cannot upgrade

trying to convert JSONObject to yaml

so below is my code

```
    private static String processFilesForYml(JSONObject a_Obj) throws Exception
    {
         
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       
        // Read file as JsonNode
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(a_Obj.toString());
        // Convert it into YAML String
        return new YAMLMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonNode); 
                     
    }
```

i am getting output like this

```
---
nlu:
- lookup: "Project"
  examples:
  - "hybrid"
  - "hybrid test"
  - "hybrid#!1"
  - "hyb_2"
```

and out expected is | pipe after example:

```
---
nlu:
- lookup: "Project"
  examples: | //pipe here
  - "hybrid"
  - "hybrid test"
  - "hybrid#!1"
  - "hyb_2"
```

is there any other way do this cannot use new jar

below is my input JSONObject

```
{
  "nlu": [
    {
      "lookup": "Project",
      "examples": [
        "hybrid",
        "hybrid test",
        "basic work management",
        "basictemplateprj",
        "seo a/b testing",
        "seotemplateprj",
        "marketing strategy",
        "marketingtemplateprj",
        "hybrid#!4"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were JSON what is the desire object?

A:

```
{
  "nlu": [
    {
      "examples": "- hybrid\n- \"hybrid test\"\n- \"hybrid#!1\"\n- hyb_2\n",
      "lookup": "Project"
    }
  ]
}
```

or  B:

```
{
  "nlu": [
    {
      "examples": [
        "hybrid",
        "hybrid test",
        "hybrid#!1",
        "hyb_2"
      ],
      "lookup": "Project"
    }
  ]
}
```

According to the desired YAML file you want the first option. This means that you are trying to serialize a list a string. I would suggest to convert your list to an object and try specifying the exact serialization

Comment: mine is B one i have updated in the question